# Prove that $V=U_1\oplus\cdots\oplus U_k$ iff $v=u_1+\cdots+u_k$

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Let $U_1,U_2,...,U_k$ be subspaces of vector space $V$. Prove that $V=U_{1}\oplus U_{2}\oplus...\oplus U_{k}$ iff every vector $v\in V$ can be written uniquely as $v=u_{1}+u_{2}+...+u_{k}$ while $\forall i\in\{1,...,k\}\quad u_{i}\in U_{I}$.

**Thoughts** I know how to prove $\Leftarrow$ but I'm confused in the other direction. I think I need to use the setting of direct sum that $0=u_{1}+u_{2}+...+u_{k}$ iff $\forall i\in\{1,...,k\}\quad u_{I}=0$, or maybe display the $U_i$ bases.

Comment: Statement is false as written. Consider $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, $U_1=\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x,y\text{ arbitrary}\}$, and $U_2=\{(0,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid y,z,\text{ arbitrary}\}$. So in fact, what you claim to have proven is incorrect.

Comment: The sum $v=u_1 + \cdots + u_k$ with $u_i \in U_i$ must be unique. The direction $\implies$ is only the definition.

Comment: @AdlerMarques I didn't consider the that the combination is unique, so thank you for bring it up.